# Php how number is double or odd

Tags: php

I looked at some questions and answers but didn't find anything. I would like to determine if a number is odd or even. How I can do that?

Example:

```
odd_or_even(567);

// returns odd
```

Comment: odd ok, but double? double what now?

Comment: What do you mean by "double"? Do you mean "[double-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)" or "[even](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_number)"?

Comment: Do you mean 'odd or even'?

Comment: The word he is looking for is "even". Divisible by two.

Comment: has SO come down to this!

Comment: @YetiCGN I guess that's a fair assumption.

Comment: google translator is not good enough to ask programming questions

Answer (score 1):

Use [modulo](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php):

```
if ($id % 2 === 0) {
    echo 'even';
} else {
    echo 'odd';
}
```